# PerlXS: Possible crash trying to free()

Tags: perl, xs

I am seeing subtle crashes, which I think is down to the following XS code:

```
void
tiff_ReadRawStrip (tif, strip, size)
            TIFF            *tif
            uint32_t        strip
            tmsize_t        size
INIT:
            void            *buf;
            tmsize_t        stripsize, bufsize;
PPCODE:
            stripsize = TIFFStripSize(tif);
            buf = (unsigned char *)_TIFFmalloc(stripsize);
            bufsize = TIFFReadRawStrip(tif, strip, buf, size);
            if (bufsize > 0) {
                XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSVpvn(buf, bufsize)));
            }
            _TIFFfree(buf);
```

Am I trying to free `buf` twice? Is there something else going on?

### Background info

Some years ago, I wrote [Graphics::TIFF - Perl bindings for libtiff](https://github.com/carygravel/graphics-tiff) and have been using them successfully in various other Linux-based projects. More recently, I got them to compile on Windows in Github actions.

Now a project using Graphics::TIFF is seeing [random crashes on Windows during unit testing](https://github.com/carygravel/Perl-PDF-Builder/runs/4010720394?check_suite_focus=true), which seem to be caused by Graphics::TIFF. I can only reproduce them in Github actions, as I don't have access to a Windows machine.

The Linux runners pass with no problems, so perhaps the Windows compiler is less forgiving about something.

Comment: The module seems to install fine on Windows 11 with Perl version 5.32.1. Here is the output I get when I try to install the module from CMD: https://pastebin.com/hcWFSpRZ

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The Windows runners for the Graphics::TIFF project themselves pass without problem. The errors I am see are the unit cases in this unreleased version of PDF::Builder, which uses Graphics::TIFF for the TIFF handling: https://github.com/PhilterPaper/Perl-PDF-Builder

Comment: You are welcome, however I am not seeing any test failures for `PDF::Builder`: https://pastebin.com/vqvkTvCS

Comment: `newSVpvn` "Creates a new SV and copies a string into it", so no double-free. But aren't you're missing a `XSRETURN(bufsize > 0 ? 1 : 0)` at the end?

Comment: That would certainly speed things up, but how do I get Perl to run _TIFFfree() when the SV is destroyed?

Comment: @ikegami - I had assumed that XPUSHs dealt with the stack size, but if that is not the case, I am sure you are right.

Comment: `XPUSH*` makes sure there's enough space on the stack, but that's all it does in addition to `PUSH*`. For example, a function that takes one argument and returns one value wouldn't need to use `XPUSH*` since you already know there's space for one. It's possible `XSRETURN` isn't needed when using (X)PUSH (rather than assigning to `ST`). Not sure about that.

Comment: In fact, it looks like `XSRETURN*` isn't needed then.

Comment: @zevzek You are absolutely right about the cast. I don't know what was thinking. I released v18 of Graphics::TIFF without it. I didn't expect it to solve the random crashes, and it hasn't, unfortunately.